# Can final static change when referring to method?

Tags: java, static, final

Can the value of a `final static` field change when it refers to a method? For example, if you run the following code:

```
private static final String example = Example.getExampleString();
```

Can the value of `example` change when the method `getExampleString()` returns something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have in your question is an *initializer*. As a result, `Example.getExampleString()` is called **once** when the variable is first defined in memory, and after that, `example` will contain the value the function returned that one time it was called.

So if you run your program twice, the variable could have a different value for each run, but once the variable is set, it can't be changed while the program is running.

As an example, try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class VarTest {
    private static final Random rng = new Random();
    private static final String example = Integer.toString(rng.nextInt());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(example);
        System.out.println(rng.nextInt());
        System.out.println(rng.nextInt());
        System.out.println(example);
    }
}
```

If you run this program, you'll see that `nextInt` returns different values with each call, but `example` remains constant within the program. If you run it a second time, `example` can be different than the last time you ran it, but `example` still doesn't change during runtime. (You may need to wait a few seconds or minutes between runs to see different values of `example` because of how `Random` works.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. `example` is `final` and initialized to the reference value returned by `getExampleString()` when the class is initialized. Since it is `final`, the variable cannot be reassigned with another reference value.

<sub>You can do it through reflection, but that has nothing to do with the method you are invoking in the initialization expression.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting the part that the variable is final static, the method itself is called only once to provide a String.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked if it is possible then answer is ***unfortunately yes***.
But you need to remember that purpose of `final` fields it to let programmer set its value only once so **you should never try to change it**.
Below is example of how you can do it, but this is only for (bad)education purpose.

---

Since result of `Example.getExampleString()` can't be *considered compile-time constant expression* then this `example` is not considered *constant variable* so its value will not be inlined in code which will use `example`. So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/1393766) you can do something like

```
class Example {

    private static final String example = Example.getExampleString();

    private static String getExampleString() {
        return "foo";
    }

    static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Example.example);
        setFinalStatic(Example.class.getDeclaredField("example"), "bar");
        System.out.println(Example.example);
    }
}
```

which will return

```
foo
bar
```

So as you can see in this case it was possible to change value of `example` field.